# How to reinstall Windows after dual-boot broke it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have install Ubuntu 18.04 a few days ago as dual-boot mode (the other OS is Windows 10). After I installed it, I can only boot into Ubuntu and automatic repair mode of Windows 10.

So I think my Windows 10 is corrupted or something. How can I know which disk I installed Ubuntu on? After I know it, I would like to remove Ubuntu again and reinstall Windows 10. So basically my question is how to remove ubuntu and reinstall Windows 10 when I can only boot into Ubuntu. I have no other computer.

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. This will make your Windows partition visible again from the start screen.

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted my efi boot partition. How to know which disk where I deleted my efi system partition?

Comment: I think you’re asking the wrong question - if you want to remove Ubuntu and reinstall windows, you don’t need to identify your Ubuntu partition at all - just use the windows installation media and it’ll take care of it. If you want to reinstall Ubuntu after, leave enough free space for that. Obviously, if you want to install Windows alongside Ubuntu (ie not overwrite your Ubuntu partition), you’ll need to know what partition is Ubuntu.

Comment: If it’s your only computer, do make sure you create all the installation media you’ll need before you delete any of your OS’s! You’ll have trouble creating installation media if you don’t have a working OS.